# github integration with 3rd party services not designed to accept github events

Tags: github

I am trialing integration of various 3rd party websites into github.

Github provides webhooks which provides notifications of events occurring to your repositories incluing github specific details (see https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).  However, this requires that the 3rd party service be designed specifically for github.

As far as I can tell github does not seem to allow me to generate custom static payloads to be sent to an existing server that cannot directly use the default content.  A simple example of this is go report card (see https://goreportcard.com/) which needs an event similar to the following (generated by clicking the "Refresh Now" button on the website e.g. from goreportcard.com/report/github.com/RidiculousRichard/sandbox):

```
Request URL:https://goreportcard.com/checks
Request Method:POST
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Payload Body: repo=github.com%2FRidiculousRichard%2Fsandbox
```

As far as I can tell I cannot get github to emit the above custom event.  **Is this correct?**

In the above case I could use a CI engine such as travis to make the desired custom event since they logically both depend on the same github push event.
It is not clear to me that using a CI engine build is an appropriate, possible, efficient and within the CI engine ToS & free usage for handling other github events like commit_comment, pull_request, pull_request_review, pull_request_review_comment, status, issues and issue_comment.

I could write and host a webserver (e.g. through appserver using the free tier limits here: cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas) to receive all events and then do the appropriate tie in to any 3rd party service.
I am hoping to avoid doing this as it seems overkill for performing what seems to be a relative simple HTTP request payload translation.
**Does there already exist a 3rd party service that will let me provide custom HTTP request payload modification and forward the request to the right 3rd party server?**.

(This is where I look stupid with a 'let me google that for you' response; I swear it wasn't in any of my search responses.)